# How do I fix 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404

I have converted my website from html to wordpress but the scripts are not loading. What could be the problem?

```
//This is the code for the functions.php file

<?php


function load_stylesheets()

{

    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');

    wp_register_style('font', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/all.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('font');

    wp_register_style('slider', get_template_directory_uri().'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('slider');

    wp_register_style('scroll', get_template_directory_uri().'https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('scroll');

    wp_register_style('custom', get_template_directory_uri().'/custom.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('custom');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_stylesheets');

//Load Scripts

function addjs()
{


    wp_register_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', array(), 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');


    wp_register_script('bootstrap1', get_template_directory_uri() . 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js', array(), 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap1');


    wp_register_script('bootstrap2', get_template_directory_uri() . 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap2');


    wp_register_script('parallax', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/parallax.min.js', array(), 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('parallax');


    wp_register_script('slider', get_template_directory_uri() . 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js', array(), 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('slider');


    wp_register_script('countdown', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/jquery.countdown.min.js', array(), 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('countdown');


    wp_register_script('scroll', get_template_directory_uri() . 'https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js', array(), 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('scroll');


    wp_register_script('scroll1', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/aos-settings.js', array(), 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('scroll1');


    wp_register_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/scripts.js', array(), 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts');


    wp_register_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array(), 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom');

}
```

page inspection console
[image: page inspection console]

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `get_template_directory_uri()` for external links.

Solution:

```php
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js', false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('bootstrap', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', 'jquery', false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
```

Use this for all the *https://...* sources and

```php
    wp_register_style('custom', get_template_directory_uri().'/custom.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('custom');
```

for the files in your own theme.

Comment: cool answer :) I've edited this time, but note that you can use backquotes ` for single / few words code (like the method you were quoting)